# What's the reason behind inconsistent 'UnsatisfiedLinkError' while trying to load a .so file through JNA?

Tags: java, shared-libraries, jna, synchronized, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to load a .so file giving it's absolute path to Native.loadLibrary API. It works but I'm getting UnsatisfiedLinkError at times for which I couldn't find the reason. Can someone help me with this ?

Environment : CentOS 7.4
ImageMagick-7.0.1-2
OpenJDK : 1.8.0_162

I've set the directory path of the sharedobject file in 
-Djna.library.path , -Djava.library.path and LD_LIBRARY_PATH .
I have an action class which invokes this method from the .so file through the java interface.

Code in action class :

```
synchronized (InterfaceforSO .class) {
    InterfaceforSO.compressImage(oldPath,newPath);                                
}
```

Code in Interface class to load library :

```
public interface InterfaceforSO extends Library {
     InterfaceforSO INSTANCE = (InterfaceforSO)Native.loadLibrary(<absolute_path_of_.so_file>,InterfaceforSO.class);
     void compressImage(String path, String newPath);
}
```

Native.loadLibrary throws exception **at times**. Failure rate is like 3/5. 
The exception is :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library '<absolute_path_of_.so_file>': Native library (<absolute_path_of_.so_file>) not found in resource path ([file:/transltr/imgmagic/WEB-INF/classes/, file: <...... jars present in the WEB-INF/lib directory>.
```

P.S : I've placed the .so file in /transltr/imgmagic/WEB-INF/classes/ directory.

Could someone help me with this ?

Comment: `loadLibrary` takes a library name, not an absolute path. From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)) _"The libname argument must not contain any platform specific prefix, file extension or path."_

Comment: Exception is thrown only at times. Otherwise , the library method is successfully invoked and intended operation is performed by the .so file.

Comment: Set `-Djna.debug_load=true` to see where it tries to search and what looks wrong.

Comment: Also, when you mean that it fails _at times_, does it fail in such way on the **same computer** or does it always fail on some specific client machines? Have you noticed a pattern?

Comment: @cubrr : Yes I've set the debug_load and the path is looks for is where the .so file is present. About the pattern of failure : There is no specific pattern. I did a small load testing of hitting 5 requests to invoke the .so file method. 3 out of 5 requests fail because of the said exception. In doubts of synchronization , I also tested randomly with a single requests with good time interval - even this case does not guarantee a 100% success rate.

Comment: @JornVernee I tried what you said , and I get the below mentioned exception at times : 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: **libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.so.0**: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

ldd command output for the .so file shows : 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  
 **libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.so.0** => /opt/ImageMagick-7.0.1-2/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.so.0 
 libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.0 => /opt/ImageMagick-7.0.1-2/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.0
        ...
It is present in dependencies with right path though.